# selenium chrome headless disable-gpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Как-то давно отключал gui для chome и было моё счастье, снова вот понадобилось, но не могу понять что я делаю не так,
**инициализация с gui работает прекрасно:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='\chromedriver')
```

**инициализация без gui не работает**, ошибку не выводит, но и не получает нужные мне данные. Куда копать ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='\chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: что значит "не получает нужные данные"? Какой точно код используете? Какой результат ожидали? Что вместо этого получаете конкретно? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, не работало потому что блокировал защитник windows